# dynamic obstacle layer not working on global costmap

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using the following plugins for global costmap:

> plugins:

```
  - {name: navigation_map, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer" }
  - {name: obstacles,  type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer" }
  - {name: inflation,  type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer" }
```

and in the same way I use these for my local costmap:

> plugins:

```
 - {name: obstacles,  type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer" }
 - {name: inflation,  type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer" }
```

In this context I have 2 scans (front,back) added to my obstacles observation_sources, dynamic obstacles can be seen in the local costmap but not in the global costmap.

I have no idea what could cause that, since it is working in local costmap most trivial problems can be eliminated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404667/dynamic-obstacle-layer-not-working-on-global-costmap/) by [Ammar Albakri](https://answers.ros.org/users/106635/ammar-albakri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2022-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you dump your parameters when your system is running, make sure the parameters are set the way you expect them to be.

Check for any warnings in the terminal that might give a hint why the global isn't working.

Make sure that the global and local costmap appear where you expect them to be spatially in RViz.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2022-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ammar Albakri](https://answers.ros.org/users/106635/ammar-albakri/) on 2022-09-20**:
I solved this problem thanks, it was my urdf. my wheel links were on the ground with no height at all (like on the same level with map)